# Bash sed remove before and after a found string

Tags: bash, sed

I currently have the following code:

`sed -i "/# My Comment Text/,+2d" /etc/crontab`

This removes the 2 lines after this line '# My Comment Text', but I also want it to remove 1 line above this found string. How can I resolve this inside my 1 liner sed command?

Comment: [Delete lines before and after a match in bash (with sed or awk)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11793942/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

Here's 2 sed commands to do the trick. If your input file looks like

```
1
2
3
4 # My Comment Text
5
6
7
8
```

The we want to delete lines 3,4,5,6.

```
$ sed '/# My Comment Text/ {h;N;N;g}' file  | tac | sed '/# My Comment Text/,+1d' | tac
1
2
7
8
```

The first sed command deletes the 2 lines after the matched line, without deleting the matched line.
Then we reverse the file and delete the matched line and the line after (which is the preceding line in the normal file.
Re-reverse the input and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I used `gsed` on the mac for GNU sed. On linux you should be able to use plain old `sed`.

`$ seq 10 | sed 's/^5/5 # my comment text/' | gsed -e ':b;$!{N;1bb;};/# my comment text/,+2!P;D'
1
2
3
7
8
9
10`